# MSAccess Query to treat text field as columns

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

I need to analyze some data that lives on a SharePoint server and the way it was set up looks like this:

```
Campaign ID         | Changes
------------------------------------
12345               | 56789 - Name 1
                      98766 - Name 2
                      54789 - Name 3
------------------------------------
67890               | 98764 - Name 4
                      56789 - Name 1
------------------------------------
```

So each change text field rows are separated by a newline and delimited by a dash

I'm trying to figure out how to query and return something that looks like this:

```
Campaign ID         | ChangesID | Name
------------------------------------
12345               | 56789     | Name 1
12345               | 98766     | Name 2
12345               | 54789     | Name 3
67890               | 98764     | Name 4
67890               | 56789     | Name 1
```

Any ideas?